# How do I write a jasmine test for a method that contains a global variable from another class/file?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, fixtures, jasmine

My tests fails for the following reason:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: moving_canvas_context in file
>   (line 5)

I understand the reason the test is failing. It doesn't understand the variable since it is defined in a separate JavaScript file. However, it is declared globally and works in reality.

How do I write a jasmine test for this `clear_canvas` function?

JavaScript `Canvas_Actions`:

```
(function() {
  window.Canvas_Actions = (function() {
    function Canvas_Actions() {}
    Canvas_Actions.prototype.clear_canvas = function() {
      moving_canvas_context.clearRect(0, 0, moving_canvas.width, moving_canvas.height);
      main_canvas_context.drawImage(window.background_image, 0, 0, main_canvas.width, main_canvas.height);
      return window.canvas_objects = [];
    };
    return Canvas_Actions;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

Jasmine Test for `Canvas_Actions`:

```
(function() {
  describe('Canvas Actions', function() {
    return describe('clear_canvas', function() {
      return it('clears the canvases and deletes all objects', function() {
        var actions;
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "../spec/javascript/fixtures";
        loadFixtures("canvas_fixture.html");
        actions = new Canvas_Actions();
        actions.clear_canvas();
        return expect(canvas_objects).toEqual([]);
      });
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it is declared globally and works in reality

Well, it also needs to be declared when the test runs. So you're probably missing a reference to the script where it is defined in the testing fixture html.

Also, global variables are normally not a good idea, they tend to create difficult bugs. Since you're already using jasmine as a testing framework, try to abstract the dependency on that global variable in something that you pass to your code under test. Then, use jasmine's mocking abilities to test it.

If you remove the global references from `Canvas_Actions`, it could look like this:

```
var Canvas_Actions = function(canvas) { 
  this.canvas = canvas; 
}
Canvas_Actions.prototype.clear_canvas = function(background_image) {
  var canvas = this.canvas;
  canvas.getContext().clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.getContext().drawImage(background_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.clearObjects();
};
```

You can mock the `canvas` argument with jasmine and test `Canvas_Actions` in isolation.

As can be noted, this code might *unearth* a `Canvas` class, and you might find out that `clear_canvas` belongs in there. Use the tests to guide your design, one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer was very helpful.  Following your example, if I remove all the global references, how would you test a method such as clearRect or drawImage that deals with drawing on the canvas?  mocks?

Comment: Yes, mocks for your objects in isolation, but more integration style checks for objects that deal with external objects. These are just tests that exercise an external object and check its state for the intended behavior under test.

Answer (score 4):

Jordão is absolutely right, however there's an ugly option too.
Attach your global object to the window in beforeEach method. Code below probably does not work (haven't tested it), but should be good enough to understand how to work around this jasmine global object problem.

```
(function() {
  describe('Canvas Actions', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        window.Canvas_Actions = (function() {
function Canvas_Actions() {}
Canvas_Actions.prototype.clear_canvas = function() {
  moving_canvas_context.clearRect(0, 0, moving_canvas.width, moving_canvas.height);
  main_canvas_context.drawImage(window.background_image, 0, 0, main_canvas.width, main_canvas.height);
  return window.canvas_objects = [];
};
return Canvas_Actions;
})();
    });
return describe('clear_canvas', function() {

  return it('clears the canvases and deletes all objects', function() {
    var actions;
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "../spec/javascript/fixtures";
    loadFixtures("canvas_fixture.html");
    actions = window.Canvas_Actions;
    actions.clear_canvas();
    return expect(canvas_objects).toEqual([]);
  });
});
  });
}).call(this);
```

**EDIT:** as per comments by @John Henckel and @serv-inc apparently there might be an error (`ReferenceError: window is not defined`) to fix it instead of `window` use `global` like: `window.Canvas_Actions` change to `global.Canvas_Actions`

Comment: This does not work.  When I run `npm test` then I get error 'ReferenceError: window is not defined'.  I guess jasmine is running in headless browser, so there isn't any window.

Comment: @JohnHenckel: see below

Answer (score 3):

It [seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953792/changing-global-variable-values-in-jasmine-test) JasmineJS uses the `global` property. So @Jordão's answer nonwithstanding, you could replace

```
window.Canvas_Actions = (function() {
```

with

```
global.Canvas_Actions = (function() {
```