# changing global variable values in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

We use global variables like this for a jasmine test batch in our react app.

```
global.serverVars = {
language: 'en-us',
context: 'testing',
```

};

In one of the Spec which tests different languages, I want to change value of `global.serverVars.language` to `nl-nl`

I am not sure how to achieve that. Any suggestion would be helpful.
I mean, is it good practice to change global variable values on the fly or there is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call your global variable in `beforeEach` or `before` Method before executing the test-cases?.

```
(function() {
  describe('Canvas Actions', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
       global.serverVars.language: 'nl-nl',
    });
  });
})()
```